# Wake On Lan on dual boot machine (Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, suspend, power-management, wakeonlan

I have one SSD with separate partitions for Ubuntu and Windows. After turning the machine on, I can select which OS to boot. After 10 seconds of doing nothing, Ubuntu loads. **I want to be able to wake the machine (Ubuntu) through LAN.**

I have an MSI Z270 Gaming M5 motherboard. In the BIOS, I've set Resume By PCI-E Device to be Enabled, and in Power Management Setup, the ErP (EuP in the [Manual](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z270-GAMING-M5#down-manual)) is Disabled.

`ifconfig -> enp3s0, lo`

`sudo ethtool enp3s0 -> **Supports Wake-on: d** Wake-on: d`

Why is it that Supports Wake-on gives d (meaning disabled)? So that when I do:

`sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g`

I get:

`Cannot set new wake-on-lan settings: Operation not supported not setting wol`

After realising that settings in Windows may get in the way, following [this guide](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-wake-on-lan-windows-10/), I did:

1. Device Manager -> Network Adapters -> adapter right click Properties -> Power Management tab: Check everything; and in the the Advanced tab: Wake on Magic Packet was already enabled.
2. In Power Options <kbd>Sup</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> I've **disabled** `Turn on fast startup`

After that in Ubuntu, `ethtool` still gives `Supports Wake-on: d`. Yet I've tried to wake on LAN, thinking that maybe the Windows settings enables me to wake the computer from sleep if I suspend it from Ubuntu. But no success. The "to be waked up on LAN" machine is connected to a router via ethernet. I connected to that router with a laptop and gave the command in a terminal:

`wakeonlan macaddress`

But this does not wake up the computer.

I'm out of ideas now. Do you have any ideas, suggestions, please?

Edit:
On an [archlinux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN) some related info is mentioned about known issues. I searched for my NIC (Network Interface Card). According to my [MSI Z270 Gaming M5 motherboard's page](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z270-GAMING-M5/Specification) in the DETAIL section of the Specification, I have a Killer E2500 LAN controller. The archlinux wiki page mentions exactly this card for having a bug that it sometimes wakes up unintentionally, and so WOL has been disabled. It mentions some patches which both restores WOL and fixes the underlying bug. I will go after it and hopefully will be able to bring WOL to life. If so, I will update this thread accordingly.

Comment: In the mentioned archlinux wiki there seem to be people that successfully set up WOL on this motherboard, but I had no success doing so. I should add that I haven't tried too hard.